# Custom theme for Android in Xamarin not being found

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Visual Studio.

In my MainActivity.cs file I am trying to set a custom theme. The Activity attribute looks like this: `[Activity(Label = "MyTest", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Idkred", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]`

When I try and build I am getting: `error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.Idkred').`

I have a values folder in my Android resources folder. In there is a styles.xml file. The styles.xml file's build action is AndroidResource.

It looks like it is getting processed because in the build output I see `Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml`.

My styles.xml file has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Idkred" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_idkred</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Idkred</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Idkred</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Idkred</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Idkred</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Idkred</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_idkred</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_idkred</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Idkred</item>
    </style>

... (more styles)
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the `android:` namespace.

```
[Activity(Label = "MyTest", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.Idkred", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

This namespace is only for resources that come from Android it self.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.